# How to pass an array in a JSON request in Jmeter

Tags: arrays, json, jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I have to pass a JSON in the HTTP request and that JSON contains an array of addresses. Up until I add the array, the request is fine and I do get a response but as soon as I add the array of addresses, I get a bad request error

Below is my bad request

```
{
  "searchType": "XXXXXX",
  "searchCriteria": {
    "firstName": "J",
    "lastName": "S",
    "birthYear": 1980,
    "birthMonth": 1,
    "birthDay": 1
    "addresses":{
            "address": [
               {
                  "_city": "LOUISVILLE",
                  "_state": "TN",
                  "_zip": "37777-3917"
               },
               {
                  "_address1": "920 E LAMAR ALEXANDER PARKWAY",
                  "_city": "MARYVILLE",
                  "_state": "TN",
                  "_zip": "37804"
               },
               {
                  "_address1": "Last Reported Address - Out of State",
                  "_city": "LOUISVILLE",
                  "_state": "TN",
                  "_zip": "37777"
               }
            ]
         }
  },
  "identification": {
    "ipAddress": "XXXXXXXX",
    "applicationID": "XXXX"
  }
}
```

Can someone please guide me how this can be achieved in Jmeter?

Answer (score 1):

What you provide is not a valid [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) you can double check it using an online [JSON validator](https://jsonlint.com/)

Since we don't have any idea regarding how the "good" request should look like we cannot come up with the 100% valid solution.

You can try to use the below JSON payload as the reference, it's syntactically correct but I don't guarantee your application will accept it:

```
{
  "searchType": "XXXXXX",
  "searchCriteria": {
    "firstName": "J",
    "lastName": "S",
    "birthYear": 1980,
    "birthMonth": 1,
    "birthDay": {
      "addresses": {
        "address": [
          {
            "_city": "LOUISVILLE",
            "_state": "TN",
            "_zip": "37777-3917"
          },
          {
            "_address1": "920 E LAMAR ALEXANDER PARKWAY",
            "_city": "MARYVILLE",
            "_state": "TN",
            "_zip": "37804"
          },
          {
            "_address1": "Last Reported Address - Out of State",
            "_city": "LOUISVILLE",
            "_state": "TN",
            "_zip": "37777"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "identification": {
    "ipAddress": "XXXXXXXX",
    "applicationID": "XXXX"
  }
}
```

I would recommend recording the request which is successful using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) and once you have a working request which you can successfully replay you can [correlate](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) dynamic and [parameterize](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-parameterization-the-complete-guide/) user-specific values.

Comment: Yes the attached json was not in the correct format. Once I corrected it, started to work. thanks @Dmitri.